# Do member account need to join Apple Membership Program if added into an Organizations's Account team ?

Tags: ios

This may be a silly question, but i read all detail in the link below and still confusing.

https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/

Question: I need to create a new (and first) Apple ID for my company (that hasn't experimented in iOS development before) and join Apple Developer Program for Organizations. But i still not understand :

1. Is it true that my company only need to pay once (99$/year) for the Team Agent account ? If we add another members, do their account need to be a Paid Account or just an Apple ID is enough ?
2. If 1's answer is YES, is there any limitation for the number of member that Team Agent account can add ?

Please help, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes, company needs to pay once per year. But account must be organization account, as mentioned in your link, you should have legal entity status (or name), DUNs number etc. to register as organization account.

For adding new members there is no need for paid account. 
check how to manage team at reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

2. As of my knowledge there is no limit for adding members (or developers)

Hope this helps